# Installing Notepad++ C compiler plugin: linintl-8.dll is missing

Tags: c, compiler-construction, notepad++

Following the instructions on http://iitdu.forumsmotion.com/t108-gcc-compiler-in-notepad

However, upon execution of NPPExec with the code provided **(below)**, ld.exe displays a warning detailing that linintl-8.dll is missing.

```
// The script code, C source code compiling with GNU CC (GCC) in notepad++ (by "NppExec" plug-in) and compressing with UPX...
//
// Enable? "//" signs remove in code line.
// Sample: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o $(NAME_PART)

YOUR_GCC\BIN\_PATH_HERE\gcc.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o $(NAME_PART)

// UPX Compress (with "--best, --ultra-brute" options)
// Enable? "//" signs remove in code line.
// Sample: C:\WINDOWS\system32\upx.exe --best --ultra-brute $(NAME_PART).exe

YOUR_UPX_PATH_HERE\upx.exe --best --ultra-brute $(NAME_PART).exe
```

Yet, I can see linintl-8.dll sitting in the bin directory of mingw.

Does anybody have any idea how this issue can be resolved, or alternatively an entirely different method to successfully compile C in notepad++ ?

Comment: shouldn't that be somewhere in system or system32 ?

Comment: not sure, that's why I posted a comment, you could try it :)

Comment: Did you install Mingw separately, or did it come with the IDE? You should try to simply reinstall Mingw, using the pre-made installer which you can download from the [Mingw site](http://www.mingw.org/wiki). There should be no need to register DLLs manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Windows expert, but I know that dlls should go somewhere in `C:/System` or `C:/System32` for Windows 7 you should check this question:

[How do I register a DLL file on Windows 7 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-on-windows-7-64-bit)