# VBS - Register and use Dsofile Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: dll, vbscript, dllregistration, dsofile

I'm trying to use [Dsofile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692828.aspx) with a VBS script on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I believe my issue is with registering the DLL.

I used this to register the DLL

```
regsvr32 D:\Desktop\dsofile.dll
```

and am told that

```
"DllRegisterServer in D:\Desktop\dsofile.dll succeeded."
```

leading me to believe that everything worked. When I try to run the test code that Microsoft gives

```
Set objFile = CreateObject("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties")
objFile.Open("D:\Desktop\test.xls")
Wscript.Echo "Author: " & objFile.SummaryProperties.Author
```

it fails on the first line, stating that

```
"ActiveX component can't create object: 'DOSFile.OLEDocumentProperties"
```

which leads me to believe that the DLL did not actually register correctly.

I then tried registering the DLL, based off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4885637/1117216) solution, by doing the following

```
cd \Windows\SysWOW64
regsvr32 C:\dsofile.dll
```

It also informs me that it registered correctly, but once again the script fails on the first line.

How can I fix this, so that I can use Dsofile?

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to use the 32-bit script interpreter from c:\windows\syswow64.  You'll need to wean yourself off dsofile, it has no future.

Comment: Using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe test.vbs` to execute the script fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @HansPassant: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Because there are thousands of programmers that depend on dsofile that will take out their anger at me.  They do shoot messengers around here.

Comment: @HansPassant, You are right. I am one of the programmer in that thousand. What is your alternate for DSO ? Is it the Open Office SDK?

Comment: A "robert8w8" recompiled the DSOFile.dll for 64 bits and posted at CodeProject: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1118708/Bit-Application-Cannot-Use-DSOfile ... I used this DLL on a small VBA project of mine with no errors. However, it didn't work for me because I'm trying to update metadata on a MP4 file. And I haven't found a way to do this, yet.