# How to register a 64-bit COM dll on 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: visual-c++, com, atl, windows-7-x64, regsvr32

I'm trying to register an x64 COM server dll for use in x64 office on x64 windows 7. I have followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-on-windows-7-64-bit) but I cannot register the dll. When I attempt to I get the following error:

[image: regsvr error message]

The command I use is `regsvr32 my_x64_com_server.dll`

Why is this happening and is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be the default for an unqualified path, but have you tried explicitly running `%windir%\System32\regsvr32.exe my_x64_com_server.dll`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How is the command being run?  From a process or from a command line?

Make sure the command is being run from a 64-bit process (or a 64-bit cmd.exe console window).  Otherwise, the `%windir%\System32\regsvr32.exe` command will be redirected to `%windir%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe` and a 32-bit regsrv32 will be run (which can't register 64-bit DLLs).

You could also try using `%windir%\sysnative\regsvr32.exe` which will redirect to the real `%windir%\System32\` directory (but only from a 32-bit process, so if you use that take care to make sure no one tries to run the command from a 64-bit process).

See [File System Redirector on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, everyone. My issue is resolved but I'm not sure why. I cleaned and rebuilt all of my sources and followed the instructions, above, and everything worked as expected.

Comment: I do not have a `sysnative` dir here. What are you really meaning with it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when I was upgrading windows 2003 to window 2012 server. Below solution helped me to resolve it. I had to register the dll as 32 bit.

**

**- Solution:**

**Open Command prompt as Administrator

**Type the directory where you want to execute the dll
execute regsvr32