# Qt based ActiveX works well in x86 platform target but not in x64?

Tags: c#, qt, activex

I created an ActiveX using a **Qt** based project in order to use it in **C#**, Now I can use this object in a **32-bit application**, but When I select **x64** platform target, my C# project stops working at beginning with this error:
[image]

I compiled the activeX dll using 32-bit platform target, because If I compile it using 64 bit platform target, I wont able even to register it !

Comment: Might be the easiest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778383/how-to-register-a-64-bit-com-dll-on-64-bit-windows-7

Comment: `I compiled the activeX dll using 32-bit platform target, because If I compile it using 64 bit platform target, I wont able even to register it !` -> Can you explain that, please? Also, can you show your source code?

Comment: @lpapp It's about 2000 lines of code. How can I place it here ?! I understood that I have to register both 32bit and 64bit versions in order to use the COM object.

Comment: @saeed: not 2000 lines, but an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152449/32-bit-activex-control-in-a-64-bit-net-app

Comment: You can't load 32 bit Activex in a 64 bit application. I think the question should be about registering the 64bit Activex.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using ActiveX component at design time then you can do this using `dll Surrogates`. There are a few registry entries that you have to make to get it working. If you your ActiveX dll depends upon other ActiveX component then you need to surrogate them also.

In registry,

1. Goto `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Wow6432Node/CLSID/{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}` where xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx is you ActiveX component's GUID.
2. Add a `REG_SZ`(string) value, name should be `AppID` and the data should be the same COM object GUID {xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}.
3. Add a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Wow6432Node/AppID`. The key should be same as the COM object GUID {xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}.
4. Add a `REG_SZ`(string) value, and name it `DllSurrogate`. Leave the value blank.
5. Create a key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Classes/AppID`, if doesn't exist. The key should be named as the COM object's GUID {xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}.
6. If this doesn't help, google for dll surrogates.

[image: Help Image from thrysoee.dk]
Image from http://thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/F12qi01x.htm

For more help, visit http://thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/ch12b.htm