# REGDB E CLASSNOTREG HRESULT: 0X80040154 while deploying a C# App

Tags: c#, dll, deployment

Good Evening Geniuses,

I'm in serious need of help.
I've got a program created in C# that works well in Visual Studios 2010(platform target x86) debug. its setup also works well on my PC.

Although it uses a third party dll(GrFingerX.dll) which is a .COM component

The problem occurs when i try to deploy it on other PCs, The setup gives a

```
`Module C:\ProgramFiles\FAF\GrFingerX.dll failed to register HRESULT -2147024770`
```

while installing

Also if i choose to ignore this and continue with the setup, it installs but gives this error on opening

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
   at FinalYProj.Main_page.InitializeComponent()
   at FinalYProj.Main_page..ctor(String User)
   at FinalYProj.logger1.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
FinalYProj
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/LIUSAKOMS/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/8YOD4B7L.5GO/CPGN14Z8.OJK/fina..tion_fc28abaf1cb21645_0001.0000_e1dc63e642dc1cef/FinalYProj.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.4926 built by: NetFXw7
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.4926 built by: NetFXw7
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
AxInterop.GrFingerXLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/LIUSAKOMS/AppData/Local/Apps/2.0/8YOD4B7L.5GO/CPGN14Z8.OJK/fina..tion_fc28abaf1cb21645_0001.0000_e1dc63e642dc1cef/AxInterop.GrFingerXLib.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

All this occur if i install on another PC other than mine(x64 bit PC).
Although my guess is the GrfingerX.dll isnt registering on other machines(. Id like to know how to make the deployment work while registering automatically .dll file in other PCs.

Thanks For reading through!

Comment: Did you register it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: No i didnt, i expected the setup to register it by itself, because it would not make sense if i do that on every user's computer

Comment: You have to register COM dlls.  That's how it works.  You register a COM dll, and then you can access its classes via their CLSID.  It's the old-school version of the GAC.  And, yes, you have to do it on every user's machine.  Installers are designed to make the process easier.

Comment: well i tried registering but it gives The module "F:\GrFingerX.dll" failed to load.... Any work around?

Comment: No idea.  I have no idea what GrfingerX is, who makes it, how it was installed on your machine, etc.  Whatever you did to get it working on your machine is what you need to do on other people's machines.

Comment: Ohh Alright ..It was from a fingerprint sdk i used for my application. I guess i av to do it the hard way, ohh by the way, is there a way i could add another executable file(.exe) to my deployment project @ Will

Comment: Dunno.  Get in contact with the GrfingerX folks and ask for a client installer.