# Error with release library while running the project for Debug library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I set up the project with a Debug library named `libtesseract302d.lib`. Additional library path is linked to the folder where `libtesseract302d.lib` is located. In the additional dependencies linker input, I set `libtesseract302d.lib`. But when I run the project, a system error comes out as `The program can't start because libtesseract302.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.` I don't have any linkage to this release lib `libtesseract302.dll`, but why this error has come out?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dll` called `libtesseract302.dll` should have come with the library. This needs to be placed in the initial working directory of your executable, or you can place it in `C:\Windows\System32` and [register it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit).

Comment: Since my project is set up for libtesseract302d.lib, I think you are talking about libtesseract302d.dll. Yes I have that dll and set path in the system path, so that it can be linked. Now the problem is I set my project for debug library "libtesseract302d.lib", but the error is for libtesseract302.dll. You mean even I set for libtesseract302d.lib, i need libtesseract302.dll in the system path?

Comment: @batuman: Since the error is complaining about a missing `libtesseract302.dll` rather than `libtesseract302d.dll`, I would assume so