# Clion how to deploy project?

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I have the following **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(Thesis)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Graph.h Graph.cpp)
add_executable(Thesis ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I am using Run->Build (as release) on a custom folder `ClionProjects\Thesis\exe\Release` and I get a single executable `Thesis.exe`. If I open that, I get the following consecutive errors:

[image: 1]

What am I missing exactly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution was to link the libraries statically. That was there is no need for an awkward .dll standing next to your .exe.

Adding a single line on the CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS -static)
```

Fixed my problem. Here is other 2 options that also work, in case you need it for some reason.

```
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static")
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static)
```

My `.exe` went from 100KB to 1MB

**Edit: A couple more cool options**

Added `-s` and `-O3` to my original `CMakeLists.txt` of my question.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -s -O3")
```

`-s` reduced size from 1MB to 650KB. [-s](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link%20Options)

`-O3` is supposed to set optimization level to 3 which is the max [-O3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize%20Options)

You can see all the options from the [gcc.gnu.org site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option%20Summary). There are too many. Use the "find" option of your browser (Ctrl + f).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 of the required DLLs.

The easiest way to resolve this is to tell the compiler to link with every library statically by using the `-static` option in GCC.

Another way is to copy those DLLs in the folder in which your executable exists.

The third way is to find those DLLs and [register them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the first option which is clearly the most convenient ? This is the point of the question, how can I do that ? I don't know how.

Comment: @Shiro: I don't know how to use Cmake, so I cannot tell you what you need to add to your makefile, but you need to figure out a way to pass the `-static` option to GCC.

Comment: I have been trying to do that unsuccessfully

Comment: @Shiro: Then you can try the second option. What exactly are you compiling?

Comment: The second option is too much of a hassle. C++11 code.

Comment: @Shiro: Have you tried the third option? (AFAIK) That is actually the proper way to deploy on Windows.

Comment: @Shiro: What solution?

Comment: I posted it as answer