# Excel VBA "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)" Location Changes

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have an Excel workbook that is used to generate quotations for customers. There is a main page where the user inputs data, and there are buttons that generate various PDFs and send them to the customer. However, one user is consistently getting an error which is preventing her from generating and sending PDFs.

I beleive it is to do with "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)". It's installed on all the users' computers. On mine, the location is "C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX" but on others it is "C:\Windows\System32\mscomctl.ocx"

The user that is experiencing issues is on a 32-bit machine, so the "mscomctl.ocx" file should be in System32. I have manually put it in there, and pointed the Common Controls reference in VBA to it. The issue is that it seems to keep reverting back to looking for it in SysWOW64. Since the folder doesn't exist, it can't find it, and thus can't produce the PDFs.

I thought that perhaps the issue was that the user was running a much older version of Office (2007) where as there are users on 2013 and 2016. I also thought that perhaps it was the mixture of 64-bit and 32-bit users. The user gets sent the workbook by other users (as the quotation process goes further, it gets passed around to the relevant users.) However, there is another user who is also on 32-bit and Office 2007, and experiences no issues.

Comment: I think you might need to register it there, not 100% tho, seems to ring a bell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: You have to register an .ocx file with RegSvr32.exe - simply placing it in a directory will not work