# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to:80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a application written in asp.net VB; it runs well on my production server. However, when I executed on my desktop / or development server, I get the 80040154 related error mentioned in my header. While doing some research, it was mentioned that the issue is a result of the **target platform** being set to run on any computer and that I need to set it to run on 64-bit. Using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, I performed the following Build >> Configuration Manager >> ... and then under "Active Solution Platform"   >> I selected "New" and added x64 to list. ...I still get the error: **Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E916A72F-7F85-4642-A2CB-CD13DAC01F55} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
Label**  As I mentioned, it works on my live server, and I'm trying to get it to run on my development server. ..Could I please get some assistance? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Some DLL is not registered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit Does your app use MS Office? You might need to install the correct version, or install the Office PIA.

Comment: The app pulls it data from an XML / XSLT file & displays the results based on input entered into a web form. ...Via DOS, after pointing to the directory containing the dll files, I attempted to register the files, but get a prompt stating: "The module Interop.Scripting.dll was loaded, but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found". Any ideal what I'm missing? I get the error-prompt respectfully for all 5 .dll files presented in the bin directory.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used a COM object in a .NET project, but you can try adding the DLLs as references in your project. `My Project>References>Add>COM>Browse`. .NET should then create the necessary Interop files.