# RunTime errorError - ActiveX component can't create object - in an MS ACCESS application

Tags: vba, ms-access, ibm-mq

I was trying to run a MS-ACCESS application (MS OFFICE 2007) which was written in VBA and connects to IBM MQ in a Windows 2012 R2 server. While doing so, I am getting the below error -

`RunTime errorError - ActiveX component can't create object`

When I debug the same, its pointing the error at the below

`Set MQS = New MQSession`

I've even registered MQAX200.dll using regsvr32.

The same app running finely on Windows 2003 R2 server - MS OFFICE 2007 - IBM MQ Version 7.5

I am sort of doomed right now. Can you please help me if I am missing anything..??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have a reference to MQAX200 in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Some things that you may want to check:

- Going from a 32bit OS in Server 2003 to a 64bit in Server 2012, so there are 2 different regsvr methods to register libraries. You may want to read the answers in this link, possibly unregister the dll & then do it again just to make sure you did it properly:

[How do I register a DLL file on Windows 7 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit)

- Assuming that's out of the way, you may need to remove the VBA reference to the prior version of MQ, then reference the new version.
- You mentioned Server 2003 had Office 2007 on it, does the new server have Office installed or is Access trying to reach the MQ app via unc path or drive letter?
- Is VBA looking for a specific drive letter/path that is now different?
- You can always fire up Access, create a new project, add the reference to MQ, then in the VBA try to instantiate the object to determine if you get a better error code you can research.
- Don't forget to check the Event Viewer for supllemental info on what caused the failed instantiation