# Unable to Call C# DLL in PHP

Tags: c#, php, dll

I have Created Simple DLL Which Includes Simple test() Function it returns "Hello India" string.

I am Getting Below Error

**"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object"**

[image]
**php.ini Settings**

1. Added this at the end of php.ini:

   ```
   [PHP_COM_DOTNET]
   extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
   ```
2. `enable_dl = On`

**C# code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DLLExample
{
    public class Calc
    {
        public String test() {
            return "Hello India";   
        }
    }
}
```

Then Simply Run above Application which Generates **"DLLExample.dll"**
Then I am Just Copy Above Generated **"DLLExample.dll"** to my PHP Project

**My PHP Project Directory**

```
DLLExample
   -DLLExample.dll
   -index.php
```

I am trying to Call **test()** Function from PHP.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    $obj = new COM("DLLExample.Calc") or Die ("Something Wrong");
    echo $obj->test();
?>
```

Comment: You need to register your DLL.

Comment: where do i need to registed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897729/3936440

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: The module "d:\xampp\htdocs\DllExample\DLLExample.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.Make sure that "d:\xampp\htdocs\DllExample\DLLExample.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Comment: I'm not the PHP oracle but i've never seen the `new` ... `or` syntax. Try to use a `try` ... `catch` block instead.